# How to run some code or command in apache on condition?

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, webserver, httpd.conf

I have a use case, where I need to execute some script or execute a Linux command if a specific condition is met in an HTTP request. I am checking if any `DELETE` method request comes to my httpd server, I want to do some work like backing up files. I am not sure how to do that with the Apache web server. But I am aware about the *if module* in Apache:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_METHOD} = DELETE">
    # execute script or Linux command
</If>
```

Is it possible with Apache? Can it be achieved in any other web server?

Answer (score 2):

You can internally rewrite the request to a server-side script (PHP, CGI, etc.) conditionally based on an element of the request using mod_rewrite on Apache. You do not need to use an `<If>` expression for this.

For example, to internally rewrite any `DELETE` request to your script `/scripts/script-to-run.cgi` then you could use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =DELETE
RewriteRule !^/?scripts/ scripts/script-to-run.cgi [L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `!^/?scripts/` simply makes sure the script is not called for requests to the `/scripts/` directory itself (to avoid a rewrite loop).

> ```
> <If "%{REQUEST_METHOD} = DELETE">
> ```

This is not syntactically valid. You need to surround the string argument (RHS of the expression) in single quotes. The `=` operator is permitted, although it's preferable to use the full form `==` to avoid confusion and be similar with other languages.

For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_METHOD} == 'DELETE'">
```

Further reading:

- [Web local application Apache: run a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529612/web-local-application-apache-run-a-shell-script)

Comment: It's always a good idea to avoid loops, although in this case the `[L]` (last) is enough for that purpose.